# SPI pins in Winstar TFT display?

Tags: spi, interface, tft

I'm trying to figure out SPI pins for [Winstar WF32DSLAJDNN0 TFT display](https://www.winstar.com.tw/uploads/files/f2fc33ae36433db02350ce0fba277627.pdf). The datasheet is not very clear on that.
I think the right pins are as below, but would be great to get that confirmed before making the PCB:

- MOSI - pin #25, "SDA"
- SCLK - pin #32, "DNC_SCL"
- CS - pin #33, "NCS"

[image]

Thanks,
Tipo

Comment: You can double check from the controller data sheet. The module data sheet says they use ILI9341V or equivalent controller.

Comment: There are 4 different parallel modes, that is clear.  There are two different serial modes.  9 bit and 8 bit.  I2C is some times called 9 bit but really has 8 bits.  I can see how I2C works but do not see how SPI works.  In all cases the data line is bidirectional.

Comment: @ronsimpson The explanation is in the controller data sheet. It does not support I2C. It only has 3-wire and 4-wire serial interface. 3-wire uses 9 bits per transaction and 4-wire uses 8 bits per transaction.

Comment: Even though the datasheet uses typical I2C naming (SDA & SCL) for the serial lines, this device does not support I2C.

Comment: Does it help to check with controller data sheet? I mean, I can't know how the controller pins are connected to display flex cable, right?